# log printf and Write connection

Tags: go

I cannot for the life of me from below golang code, why when you call write function at the bottom,

```
func write(message string) {
    log.Printf("%v\n", message)
}
```

why log.Printf calls below method

```
func (fl fileLog) Write(data []byte) (int, error ) {
    fmt.Println("does this ever get called?")
    f, err := os.OpenFile(string(fl), os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    defer f.Close()
    return f.Write(data)
}
```

Logger's printf definition is below

```
 func (*Logger) Printf ¶

func (l *Logger) Printf(format string, v ...interface{})
```

-- Full Code below, someone please explain to me why this is so please--

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    stlog "log"
    "os"
)

var log *stlog.Logger

type fileLog string

func (fl fileLog) Write(data []byte) (int, error ) {
    fmt.Println("does this ever get called?")
    f, err := os.OpenFile(string(fl), os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    defer f.Close()
    return f.Write(data)
}

func registerHandlers() {
    var msgRaw = "how are you"
    write(msgRaw)
}

func run(destination string) {
    log =  stlog.New(fileLog(destination), "", stlog.LstdFlags)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("here we go")
    run("../test.log")
    registerHandlers()
}

func write(message string) {
    log.Printf("%v\n", message)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger writes the log messages to an `io.Writer`, which is an interface defined as:

```
type Writer interface {
   Write([]byte) (int,error)
}
```

The `fileLog` type implements the `io.Writer` interface, and you set it as the output of the new logger. So whenever the logger tries to write a log, it calls the `Write` function of its writer, which is `fileLog.Write`.

Comment: "So whenever the logger tries to write a log, it calls the Write function of its writer, which is fileLog.Write."

SO, when log.Printf() gets call, it will do fileLog.Write ?

Comment: OK I got it.

A Logger represents an active logging object that generates lines of output to an io.Writer. Each logging operation makes a single call to the Writer's Write method. A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer.